# Firebase Realtime Database Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to access the firebase realtime database using the example provided on the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data).

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com/");

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

However, I am noticing that the references are not being recognized and the following errors are generating:

> error CS1061: 'FirebaseApp' does not contain a definition for 'SetEditorDatabaseUrl' and no accessible extension method 'SetEditorDatabaseUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'FirebaseApp' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Editor' does not exist in the namespace 'Firebase.Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Below is the code that I am using. As you can see, I am referencing the Firebase and Firebase.Database.

```
using System;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using UnityEngine;

public class OnetoOneChat : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    private void Start()
    {
       FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("databaseURL");
       reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }

    private void SendMessage()
    {

    }

    private void ListenForMessages()
    {

    }
}
```

These files are located in the package folder of my unity project: I am not sure what is the issue. Any insight on how I can resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The namespace `Firebase.Unity.Editor` is only available inside the UnityEditor itself and completely stripped of during the build process.

=> You can't use anything from it in a built application.

Actually why use `SetEditorDatabaseUrl`? Afaik the normal `SetDatabaseUrl` should do it.

---

If for some reason you really need the editor version (I'm not that familiar with Firebase) you would have to use Platform dependent compilation

```
using System;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

public class OnetoOneChat : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    private void Start()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
       FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("databaseURL");
#endif
       reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }

    private void SendMessage()
    {

    }

    private void ListenForMessages()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have removed the editor. However, for the FirebaseApp...., it does not work when I use SetDatabaseUrl(). I get the following error `'FirebaseApp' does not contain a definition for 'SetDatabaseUrl' and no accessible extension method 'SetDatabaseUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'FirebaseApp' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: As said I'm not that familiar with Firebase .. do you need that call at all? I can't see it in any of the GetStarted example codes .. are you sure you don't just configure that URL somewhere else?

Comment: No, I do believe I need to configure the URL so I can post and get data from the database

Comment: Was able to figure out another way to initialize. Thanks for your help